# error run php script in ubuntu server terminal

Tags: php, ubuntu-12.04, gammu

I'm really confuse right now..i make this php script to send sms with gammu and put it in my home directory

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","username","password") or die("failed");
mysql_select_db("database1") or die("Database Failed");
$not_send = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM outbox WHERE status=0");
while($sending = mysql_fetch_array($not_send)){
    $msg_id = $sending['id'];
    $text = "gammu --sendsms TEXT ".$sending['phoneNum']." -text ".$sending['content'];
    $sms = shell_exec($text);
    if(preg_match("/ok/im", $sms)){
        mysql_query("DELETE FROM outbox WHERE id = '$msg_id'");
    }
}
?>
```

I already confirm the `$text` output with `echo $text`, but when i run it in terminal with `php send_sms.php` it always say **unexpected '('**

can anyone tell me whats wrong here??Or i cant put run php script outside /var/www/??
please help me..

Comment: It's unlikely this exact script causes parse error.

Comment: @zerkms: is there any way to debug php and show where the error in ubuntu terminal??or cannot i put php script outside /var/www/??

Comment: Are you sure it's the same file ? you can use `php -l /path/file.php` to check the syntax.

Comment: @Himal: of course its the same file, wait a minute i'll try ur suggestion with -l param..

Comment: Note that your php cli might be using a different php.ini file.so make sure to enable required modules on that file as well.you can use `php --ini` to check the loaded ini file.

Comment: @Himal: now im more confuse, with param -l its say `No syntax errors detected in send_sms.php`

Comment: So how exactly you run it to get an error?

Comment: @Himal: and what output i expect to tell whats wrong with `php --ini`??if its to check `mysql.ini` then yes its loaded..

Comment: @zerkms: i run `php send_sms.php` in terminal and it say this `sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected`..

Comment: @riyaniya: it's `sh` says there is a syntax error, not php. The command you're running with `shell_exec` is wrong.

Comment: @zerkms: what do u mean the `shell_exec()` command wrong??i tried to just put `shell_exec("gammu --sendsms TEXT 12345 -text 'sending test'")` in the `send_sms.php` and again run `php send_sms.php` and works fine..please tell me where is the wrong part..

Comment: @zerkms: thank you very much for your sharp mind..so i dont quote the text part in `shell_exec()` huh..thank you very much my problem solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem thankx to @zerkms..I just dont quote the `$sending['content']` part in the earlier code...

so this is the new code:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","username","password") or die("failed");
mysql_select_db("database1") or die("Database Failed");
$not_send = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM outbox WHERE status=0");
while($sending = mysql_fetch_array($not_send)){
    $msg_id = $sending['id'];
    $text = "gammu --sendsms TEXT ".$sending['phoneNum']." -text '".$sending['content'."'"];
    $sms = shell_exec($text);
    if(preg_match("/ok/im", $sms)){
        mysql_query("DELETE FROM outbox WHERE id = '$msg_id'");
    }
}
?>
```

if you have same problem hope search engine find this...once again thank you zerkms